# How would a potential carbon tax affect oil prices?

Tags: investing, trading, commodities

I'm really new to trading and looking to learn more about futures and trading oil.

Let's say I have a view that developed nations are going to be far more bullish on carbon taxes than anyone predicts and that these taxes are going to roll out in the next 2-5 years.

My understanding of Crude Oil futures is that it's typically "hump shaped", in that futures are in contango for the front months and then backwardated in the back months (as Crude sellers are willing to sell at a loss to reduce risk.)

If I want to place a trade based off my view on carbon taxes, would I go short the back-months?

Increased carbon taxes would result in a decrease in the demand for oil resulting in lower oil prices?

Or would this be a poor way to place the trade as increased carbon taxes would mean Oil producers will cut production (as they realize the quantity demanded will be less).

Thanks for reading.

Comment: For what it's worth, at least for consumer grade gasoline, demand tends to be pretty inelastic. I.E. Changes in price have to be pretty big to reduce demand in any appreciable way.

Comment: @JohnFx, right. Let's just say that this is a large carbon tax, with the set purpose of reducing emissions.

Answer (score 1):

Current oil storage is not due to the premium of selling oil to future dates but is due to reduced demand for oil. The first situation sells long-term futures contracts while holding physical oil and benefits from contango. The second situation sells short-term contracts because the second situation is looking for immediate delivery dates.

But an investor can get about 2% contango premium by selling a 12-month futures contract. Obviously there needs to be a viewpoint that oil is not going to be higher in one year's time.

Now a bull-spread holds oil by buying the short-term contract and then the long-term contract is sold. However, a bull-spread is most profitable if oil goes up.

A bear-spread of selling the short-term contract while buying the long-term contract expects oil to go down and expects contango to narrow. But the contango is already fairly narrow.

Overall, the investor should probably just trade the short-term contract on immediate news. Or sell the long-term contract for the long-term view of a future carbon-tax and hedge it only as necessary with a buy of the short-term contract. Or, without highly speculative trading use a more systematic bear-spread. However, internal-combustion-engine car bans have been announced many years into the future and will not hurt current oil prices.